# Qliksense Window() function does not work

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to use the window() function in Qliksense but it seems that Qliksense does not recognize this function despite this [documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/WindowFunctions/window-functions.htm).
While trying to use it I've kept in mind that the table has to be loaded per the documentation but still cannot seem to get it to work. I can see that Qliksense does not recognize the function because the script editor does not highlight the window function in the same color as the other syntax. What am I missing to get this function to work?

This is the error I get when I run the script with the function enabled:

[image]

I've tried using the function in different ways like in a LOAD script after SQL script, in a precedence LOAD, and in a RESIDENT LOAD. Nothing has worked.

Comment: might be a silli question but are you using Qlik Cloud? Because this function is available on Cloud only (for now)